# How to filter curl stderr output but keep the progress meter output?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sed

I would like to filter and replace the text of curl errors with a custom message and this script piping to sed works:

```
URL=""
curl --create-dirs -o /home/user/test.dat $URL |& sed 's/curl/Custom message/g'
```

This is the output I get:

```
Custom message: no URL specified!
Custom message: try 'Custom message --help' or 'Custom message --manual' for more information
```

However, when there are no errors and curl is downloading the file I don't get anymore the progress meter which instead I want to display.

**Current output:**

This is the output I get with pipe and sed when there are no errors, notice that the progress meter is missing

```
URL="http_address"
curl --create-dirs -o /home/user/test.dat $URL |& sed 's/curl/Custom error/g'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

**Desired output**

This is the output obtained by commenting out pipe and sed when there are no errors, notice that the progress meter is shown:

```
URL="http_address"
curl --create-dirs -o /home/user/test.dat $URL #|& sed 's/curl/Custom error/g'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12980    0 12980    0     0   711k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

How can I filter the curl error messages but still get my desired output with the progress meter?

I have searched this forum and tried several solutions but nothing seems to work. As soon as you sed or grep curl stderr the progress meter is not shown anymore.
Also, in general the questions asked in the forums are about how to display error messages only and not to display the progress meter, instead I want to achieve the opposite.

Comment: With curl 7.21.0 I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. Which `curl --version` did you use?

Answer (score 0):

try maybe with the `sed -u`  (or --unbuffered). It does not wait until end of input to treat the content.

if it doesn not work, save output to a temporary file with a `| tee` and treat error after the end of the process.

Comment: I tried `sed -u` but it makes no difference. Also saving the output with `| tee` does not do what required because in case of errors they are displayed to terminal before I read the temporary file and filter them.